# Two mariadb instance using same persistent storage in docker

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes, mariadb

I want to start two maria-db pod with same persistent storage and any point of time I should be able to access both the instance and data should be in sync between them.

I am trying to start two mariadb instance using same volume persistent storage in kubernetes. I am able to start both the instance. I am performing the below steps.

1. Creating a persistent volume
2. Creating a persistent volume claim
3. Using the same claim name starting mariadb-instance-1.
4. Starting mariadb-instance-2 using same storage claim name.
5. Creating two services for both the instance to access from outside.

I am able to access instance-1 but when I am trying to access instance-2 its giving me error. MySQL Error: Can’t connect to local MySQL server through socket ‘/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock’.

Please find the attached dockerfiles.

Any help will be appreciated.

Please find the below git repo for db and storage yaml file which I used to create the deployment.

https://github.com/chandan493/db-as-docker

Comment: Which [type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes) of `Persistent Volume` you using? Can you show logs of pod to where you cannot connect to?

Comment: I am creating glusterfs type volume.

Comment: Who told you that having two databases writing to same storage is a good idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not run two MariaDB engines on the same storage, and if I understood you right this is what you expected. Even if you'd mount an RWX volume on two pods, if you put /var/lib/mysql of containers in two separate MaraiaDB pods in the same place, it will result in a conflict between database engines. For MariaDB clustering lookup `MariaDB Galera` - an almoust-fully-synchronous replication for MariaDB. But you'll need three db engines running for it to make sense.